# How to use GET REST method using with AFNetworking in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios9, afnetworking, xcode7.3

I am trying to get a JSON from my server, but I need to pass some parameters to the urls. I do not want to add these parameters to the URL since they contain Content-Type, DeviceType, DeviceID and Authorization.

For a simple URL request I have the following code, but response is null, please tell me what is  wrong in this code?

Constant.h

```
#define KSERVER_URL  @"http://101.127.236.85:6067/tmsservice/MobileService.svc/"

#define KAppInfo_URL @"AuthenticateEmployee"

-(void)loginRequestContentType:(NSString*) content deviceType:(NSString*) deviceT deviceID:(NSString*) devId Authorization:(NSString*) auth WithResponse: (void (^)(id responseObject, NSError *error))responseAndErr {
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",KSERVER_URL,KAppInfo_URL];

NSLog(@"URL = %@", urlString);
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[parameters setValue:@"application/json" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
[parameters setValue:@"iOS" forKey:@"DeviceType"];
[parameters setValue:@"123456" forKey:@"DeviceID"];
[parameters setValue:strGlobalfinalString forKey:@"Authorization"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

[manager GET:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    responseAndErr(responseObject, Nil);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    responseAndErr(Nil, error);
}];
```

}

Login.m

```
-(void)sendLoginRequest {
    MBProgressHUD *progressIndicator = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    progressIndicator.labelText = kLoadingTitle;
    progressIndicator.detailsLabelText = kPleaseWaitText;

    NSString *userEmail = self.userNameTextField.text;
    NSString *userPassword = self.passwordTextField.text;

    NSLog(@"Email =  %@", userEmail);
    NSLog(@"Password =  %@", userPassword);

    NSString *singleString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@:%@", userEmail,userPassword];
    NSLog(@" Login Single String = %@", singleString);

    NSData *nsdata = [singleString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // Get NSString from NSData object in Base64
    NSString *base64Encoded = [nsdata base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    // Print the Base64 encoded string
    NSLog(@"Login Encoded: %@", base64Encoded);


    strGlobalfinalString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",base64Encoded];


    NSLog(@"Login Final Encoded String: %@", strGlobalfinalString);

    [[NetwokManager sharedInstance] loginRequestContentType:@"application/json" deviceType:@"iOS" deviceID:@"123456" Authorization:strGlobalfinalString  WithResponse:^(id responseObject, NSError *error)

     {
         [progressIndicator hide:YES];

         if (!error) {

             NSLog(@"responseString = %@", responseObject);
             HomeViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
             [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
             if (responseObject == nil)
             {
                 NSLog(@"No data from server");
                 [self showAlertViewWithMessage:@"No data downloaded from server!"];
             }

             NSDictionary *resposneDict = (NSDictionary*)responseObject;
             NSLog(@"New Dictionary Data = %@", resposneDict);


             NSString *msg;
             msg = [resposneDict objectForKey:@"status"];
             if ([msg isEqualToString:@"success"])
             {


                 HomeViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];


             }
             else if ([resposneDict objectForKey:@"StatusMessage"])
             {
                 [self showAlertViewWithMessage:@"Invalid credentials, please check your credentials"];
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Which version of AFNetworking are you using? And can you post the response output please?

Comment: Response:--URL = http://101.127.236.85:6067/tmsservice/MobileService.svc/AuthenticateEmployee

Email = anji.c@totalebizsolutions.com

Password = P@ssw0rd

Network Single String = anji.c@totalebizsolutions.com:P@ssw0rd

Encoded String: Basic YW5qaS5jQHRvdGFsZWJpenNvbHV0aW9ucy5jb206UEBzc3cwcmQ=

Content Type =  application/json

Device Type =  iOS

Device ID = 123456

Authontication = Basic YW5qaS5jQHRvdGFsZWJpenNvbHV0aW9ucy5jb206UEBzc3cwcmQ=

Comment: responseString = {

    DataUpdation = "<null>";

    Employee = "<null>";

    MyApprovalList = "<null>";

    ProjectList = "<null>";

    Status =     {

        StatusCode = 700;

        StatusMessage = "Invalid credentials, please check your credentials";

    };

    TimeSheetList = "<null>";

}

Comment: AFNetworking version may be old

Comment: Can you update to AFNetworking 3.0?

Comment: Ok ! I will update n check once

Answer (score 0):

Update AFNetworking to version 3.0 or higher and try the following:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"userid":userId, @"x-session": session};
NSString *urlString = @"http://api.example.com/sampleLink";
[manager GET:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Comment: I update AFNetworking to version 3.0 but still same error
{
    DataUpdation = "<null>";
    Employee = "<null>";
    MyApprovalList = "<null>";
    ProjectList = "<null>";
    Status =     {
        StatusCode = 700;
        StatusMessage = "Invalid credentials, please check your credentials";
    };
    TimeSheetList = "<null>";
}

Comment: It seems its a server side issue, check what parameters you have to send and if you've sent them properly. It is saying that you are sending wrong credentials, check them again and let me know what happens

Comment: Thanks Hussein
I have cross check with backend  as well check on Rest client this parameters & Base key is correct. Please check once my code as well GET method n tell me where I am wrong?
Please copy my code n test once & tell me Please

Comment: I just checked your code(and tried it), the request is returning JSON, but I am sure there is something wrong with the parameters sent or on the server side. Check again or post some code so that we can help you

Comment: Can you please send your email id or Skype Id I will share my code n doc details same Parameters n link working in Android

Comment: Email: hujaber@me.com

Comment: Hello Hussein, sending